# Powershell search for .exe file

Tags: powershell

Currently im using this code to search for specific .exe file whether it exist or not.

```
[System.IO.File]::Exists('D:\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg\oscdimg.exe')
```

Is there any methods to search for specific .exe file all over my computer instead of specifying the directory? Please let me know if you have any idea. Many thanks.

Comment: `Get-Childitem` with the parameter `-filter`, look it up there are a lot of examples

Comment: Get-ChildItem will work, but it could be more efficient to find the registry entry from the installer than just search the hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from [this guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-windows-powershell-to-search-for-files/), you could use something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\ -Include *.exe" -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

It would search the entire D drive for any file that ends with .exe. If you wanted to search for the entire exe name then you could use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\ -Include "*oscdimg.exe*" -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

for a somewhat different method [*grin*], you could use the `CIM_DataFile` class to do a search. for instance, this ...

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_DataFile -Filter "FileName='Install' AND Extension='log' AND Drive='c:'"
```

... will search on the `C:` drive of the current system for a file named `Install.log`. that above line of code returned the following on my drive ...

```
Compressed : False
Encrypted  : False
Size       : 
Hidden     : False
Name       : c:\program files (x86)\mozilla thunderbird\install.log
Readable   : True
System     : False
Version    : 
Writeable  : True

Compressed : False
Encrypted  : False
Size       : 
Hidden     : False
Name       : c:\program files\mozilla firefox\install.log
Readable   : True
System     : False
Version    : 
Writeable  : True

Compressed : False
Encrypted  : False
Size       : 
Hidden     : False
Name       : c:\program files\npcap\install.log
Readable   : True
System     : False
Version    : 
Writeable  : True

Compressed : False
Encrypted  : False
Size       : 
Hidden     : False
Name       : c:\temp\chocolatey\libreoffice-fresh\6.2.4\install.log
Readable   : True
System     : False
Version    : 
Writeable  : True

Compressed : False
Encrypted  : False
Size       : 
Hidden     : False
Name       : c:\temp\chocolatey\libreoffice-fresh\6.2.5\install.log
Readable   : True
System     : False
Version    : 
Writeable  : True
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you so much. This shows much more info than what I want lol.

Comment: @JIANKAISOON - you are quite welcome! glad to help ... and it's usually better to get more info than too little info! [*grin*]